# Azure BICEP storage blob child resource failing deployment

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-automation, azure-bicep

I have following BICEP code

```
param location string = 'canadacentral'

resource storageaccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'btestb1278ba'
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }
}



resource blob2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-09-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: storageaccount
  
}
```

I get the following error

*ERROR: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX/resourceGroups/appA/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/storResourceDeploy","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"HttpResourceNotFound","message":"The request url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX/resourcegroups/appA/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/btestb12789/blobServices/blobz?api-version=2021-02-01 is not found."}]}}*

On the portal in rg deployments I see the following error
*{
"code": "DeploymentFailed",
"target": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/appA/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/storResourceDeploy",
"message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
"details": [
{
"code": "HttpResourceNotFound",
"message": "The request url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourcegroups/appA/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/btestb12789/blobServices/blobz?api-version=2021-02-01 is not found."
}
]
}*

Not sure what is the reason, its not suppose to find the resource, rather create it, any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the problem was not the above code, however the code below it, I didnt post it earlier because I didnt realize it was the one troubling.

```
resource storageaccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'btestb1278ba'
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }
}



resource blob2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-09-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: storageaccount
  
}

resource cont 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'sepcont'
  parent: blob2

    
}





resource storageaccount2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'btestb12789'
  location: location
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }

  resource blob1 'blobServices' = {
    name: 'blob'
    
  }
}
```

Precisely the following is not allowed, value of the blob service should be set to default only, it cant have any othername.

```
  resource blob1 'blobServices' = {
    name: 'blob'
    
  }
```

Once I changed the name to default, it worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Blob service in your example is `default`, but this is not the correct name for the Blob service. The Blob service name should be `blobServices`.

```
resource blob2 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-09-01' = {
  name: 'blobServices'
  parent: storageaccount
}
```

Comment: Just followed your suggestion, however I am getting the following error now.

*ERROR: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure-storage/storResourceDeploy.bicep(19,9) : Error BCP036: The property "name" expected a value of type "'default'" but the provided value is of type "'blobServices'".*

Comment: hmmm i think it might be that @2021-09-01 date.

Comment: sorry my apologies, there was another code at the bottom, which was causing the issue, i will post the bottom code as well with a complete answer.